# Stripe - Webhook Verification

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

I've been looking for quite some time now for a solution, I am yet to find one that works for me.

My code is this:

```js
router.post("/payments/webhook", (req, res) => {
  const sig = req.headers["stripe-signature"] as string;

  const endpointSecret = "whsec_...";

  let event;
  try {
    stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.body.rawBody, sig, endpointSecret);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(400).end();
    return;
  }

  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

And it returns the error:

```
StripeSignatureVerificationError: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe?
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you looked into the examples at https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/tree/master/examples/webhook-signing ? Specifically, you likely need to customise your middleware to prevent something from parsing the request body as JSON before you get it(`body.rawBody` probably isn't enough).

Comment: Thank you! I'll look at the example now.

Comment: Sadly, this didn't work. I added these bits of code `app.use( ( req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction ): void => { if (req.originalUrl === '/webhook') { next(); } else { bodyParser.json()(req, res, next); } } );` `  bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/json'}),` (as a middleware of my route) and changed `req.body.rawBody` to `req.body`

Comment: Can you add some logging and debug? When you log req.body does it match the exact body sent by Stripe(you can see this on the Event page at the bottom), including all the whitespace that is sent in the request and the order of the keys? Are you sure you're using the right `whsec_xxx` value for the endpoint?

Comment: Yes I am using the right `whsec_xxx`, Stripe doesn't actually send a raw body.